# Do columns need to match exactly when using dataadapter.update

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

I'm working on a project to import data from a Microsoft Access database into a blank MS-SQL database. The structure of the table in Access (VM) does not match up exactly with the table in MS-SQL (vlVerticalMarketing).

```
AccessTable VM                SQLTable vlVerticalMarketing                                
ID (autonumber)               VMID (PK, identity)
VM                            VerticalMarketing
                              Deleted (required)
                              Archive (required)
                              Other non-required fields
```

I'm filling the Access data into a DataTable DT using the following query:

```
select VM as VerticalMarketing, 0 as Deleted, 0 as Archive from VM where VM is not null
```

Then I change the name of the DataTable using:

```
DT.TableName = "vlVerticalMarketing"
```

From there, I pass the DataTable into a class function.

```
Public Function CopyFromDataTable(ByVal sourceDT As DataTable, ByVal TableName As String) As Boolean
    Try
        OpenDB()
        Dim DA As New SqlDataAdapter("select VerticalMarketing, Deleted, Archive from " & TableName, Me.DBConn)
        Dim CB = New SqlCommandBuilder(DA)
        CB.QuotePrefix = "["
        CB.QuoteSuffix = "]"
        DA.InsertCommand = CB.GetInsertCommand(True)
        Dim destDT = sourceDT.Copy()
        DA.Update(destDT)
```

OpenDB is a class method that I use for other things and I know is good. It sets the connection string and creates DBConn as a SqlConnection object. The rest is standard VB.Net. Everything runs without error. Both sourceDT and destDT have data in them (viewed through the DataSet Visualizer while debugging). The problem is that no data gets passed out to the SQL database.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong that is causing the SQL database not to receive the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the problem is that the rows in destDt don't have RowState.Added when you call Update on the DataAdapter ... you can check the return value of the Update statement ... i guess it will be 0 because no inserts were executed ... you could check this with sql server profiler ...

as a workaround for this you could call DataRow.SetAdded() on the rows in your destDT ...

Comment: RowState was Unchanged. Doing a loop through the rows and doing .SetAdded() fixed it right up.

Comment: It's odd that it wasn't setting the rows as added. I used the same code in another project to import data from Excel sheets into a DataSet, then passed each table through the above code into an Access database and it worked fine, without me have to set each row as added.